# Replacing variables in csv with a randomly generated variable

Tags: python, csv, random

I am wanting to replace variables in a CSV file with a randomly generated variable for each of the variables.

For instance, changing 'not available' to either 'male' or 'female'

Sample:

```
Number    Sex
0         Female
1         Male
2         Not Available
3         Male
4         Not Available
```

To:

```
Number    Sex
0         Female
1         Male
2         Female
3         Male
4         Male
```

The code that I have right now is:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

def RandomSex():
    return random.choice(['Male','Female'])



df = pd.read_csv(r'data.csv')
df2 = df.loc[: , 'Sex']
print(df2)
df.loc[(df.Sex == 'Not Available'),'Gender'] = RandomSex()
print(df2)
```

But this is changing all of the 'Not Available' to either all 'Male' or all 'Female'

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a list with random "Male" and "Female" with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
sex_unavailable = df[df.Sex == "Not Available"]
random_genders = np.random.choice(["Male","Female"], len(sex_unavailable))]
df.loc[(df.Sex == "Not Available"), "Gender"] = random_genders
```

If you need to prepopulate the "Gender" column with the original sex value you could do this before the final assigment:

```
df["Gender"] = df["Sex"]
```

Or if you want to just overwrite the "Sex" column:

```
df.loc[(df.Sex == "Not Available"), "Sex"] = random_genders
```